# How to check alertview values

Tags: iphone

This is my code :

```
self.myAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MNB" message:@"R u want to delete" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK",nil otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil] autorelease];
    [myAlert show];
```

Here I would like to process if OK button click and also for cancel button, I would like to redirect the page if OK button clicked....I need the coding, IF condition statement when OK button clicked.....pls help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIAlertView delegate methods. For example

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
      if(buttonIndex == 0) //your OK button
      {
        //Some code here
      }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1)
      {
        //Some other code
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read UIAlertViewDelegate Protocol Reference.

You can implement following methods.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to write the **Delegate method of UIAlertView** like this

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if(buttonIndex==1){
              NSLog(@"Cancelled Clicked");  
         } 
    if(buttonIndex==0){
          NSLog(@"O.K Clicked");  
         }
}
```

Will surely work :)